# Login system/register user

Tags: java, jsp, registration

I'm unsure on how I should access my parameters and then use them to register a user in my DB.

Here is the JSP code for `register.jsp`

```
<%@page import="java.util.Enumeration"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<LINK href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<title>Opret bruger</title>
<jsp:useBean id="dbconnect" class="dbconnection.dbconnect.CreateUser" scope="session"></jsp:useBean>

<jsp:setProperty name="dbconnect" property="*" />
</head>
<body>
<%
    if(dbconnect.loggedIn){
        response.sendRedirect("minprofil.jsp");
    }
%>
<form>

    <p><label for="navn">Navn:</label><input type="text" name="navn" /></p>
    <p><label for="efternavn">Efternavn:</label><input type="text" name="efternavn" /></p>
    <p><label for="alder">Alder:</label><input type="text" name="alder" /></p>
    <p><label for="email">Email:</label><input type="text" name="email" /></p>
    <p><label for="username">Brugernavn:</label><input type="text" name="username" /></p>
    <p><label for="password">Kodeord:</label><input type="text" name="password" /></p>
    <p><label for="retypepassword">Gentag kodeord:</label><input type="text" name="retypepassword" /></p>
    <p><label for="yndlingshold">Yndlingshold:</label><input type="text" name="yndlingshold" /></p>



    <p class="submit">
        <input type="submit" name="goToLogin" value="Gå til login" />
        <input type="submit" name="OpretBruger" value="Opret bruger" />
    </p>
</form>
<%


    if(request.getParameter("goToLogin")!=null)
        response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");

    if(request.getParameter("OpretBruger")!=null){
        What should i do here ? 
                "OpretBruger" means "Create user" in english

    }



%>


</body>
</html>
```

And then here is my Java bean to connect to DB and manage all that

```
package dbconnection;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.ResultSet;



public class dbconnect {
    private static Connection con;
    String username;
    String password;
    int age;
    String name;
    public Boolean loggedIn = false;
    private ResultSet rs;
    CreateUser createuserClass = new CreateUser();


    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public int getAge(){
        return age;
    }

    public String getUsername(){
        return username;
    }

    public String getPassword(){
        return password;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username){
        this.username = username;

    }

    public void setPassword(String password){
        this.password = password;
    }






    public synchronized static void init(){
        if(con!=null)
            return;

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql:///BLANKED OUT","BLANKED OUY","BLANKED OUT");  

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Could not find class, quitting.");

        }// Loading DB driver
        catch (SQLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("SQLException, quitting");
        }

    }

    public void checkLogin(){
        try { 
            PreparedStatement login = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM brugere WHERE brugernavn=? AND password=?");   // REMEMBER TO CHANGE TABLE NAME IF DIFFERENT DB IS USED!

            login.setString(1, username);
            login.setString(2, password);

            rs = login.executeQuery();


            if(rs.next()){
                loggedIn = true;
                setInfo();
            }else{
                loggedIn = false;
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("SQL exception in dbconnect, method = checklogin");
        }
    }



    public void setInfo(){
        try {
            this.name = rs.getString(1) + " " + rs.getString(2);
            this.username = rs.getString(5);
            this.age = rs.getInt(3);
        } catch (SQLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Something fucked up");
        }



    }


    // Class til at oprette brugeren. Denne får parametre fra registrer.jsp og sætter dem som globale variable
    class CreateUser{
        // navn | efternavn | alder | email | brugernavn | password | hold
        String navn;
        String efternavn;
        int alder;
        String email;
        String brugernavn;
        String password;
        String hold;
        public void setNavn(String navn){
            this.navn = navn;
        }
        public void setEfternavn(String efternavn){
            this.efternavn = efternavn;
        }
        public void setAlder(int alder){
            this.alder = alder;
        }
        public void setEmail(String email){
            this.email = email;
        }
        public void setBrugernavn(String brugernavn){
            this.brugernavn = brugernavn;
        }
        public void setPassword(String password){
            this.password = password;
        }
        public void setHold(String hold){
            this.hold = hold;
        }


        // Funktionen som skal køres for, at opdatere database table
        public void createUser(){



            try{
                PreparedStatement opretBruger = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO account VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
                opretBruger.setString(1, navn);
                opretBruger.setString(2, efternavn);
                opretBruger.setInt(3, alder);
                opretBruger.setString(4, email);
                opretBruger.setString(5, brugernavn);
                opretBruger.setString(6, password);
                opretBruger.setString(7, hold);

                opretBruger.executeUpdate();




            }catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println(navn + " " + efternavn + " " + alder);
                System.out.println("Problemer med, at oprette bruger...");
            }
        }
    }



}
```

My login system works fine, but I have trouble on how I should make my User registration work. 
I would like to make a seperate class and use that bean to handle user registration without having to reconnect to DB and so on. It's to reuse code and save time.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: There's too much wrong in the code that I don't know where to start answering. So here's just a link to get started and get the basic concepts straight: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsp/info. It contains in turn a lot of useful links as well (which each in turn contains a lot of useful links as well).

Answer (score 1):

If a user presses on "CreateUser" then you can forward the request and response to a controller servlet/JSP.

The controller servlet will acquire all parameters from the request, store them in an ENUM (since you are using one), it will open a DB connection (by creating an instance of your DB class (dbconnect) and then call a method on it, passing the data or the ENUM) and your DB class will update your database.

The controller servlet will then forward the response to another JSP page or another view with confirmation.

These are pretty much the basics of the Model-View-Controller (MVC) pattern, where you have the controller servlet, your model or in your case the dbconnect class (business model mutator) and then bunch of JSP pages which represent the view.

It is one, i repeat ONE, of the ways you can handle your situation.

Regards!